# Android select tab from activity

Tags: android, android-listfragment, android-cursoradapter

In my application i have a FragmentPagerAdapter with 4 tabs. Each tab contains a Listfragment, except the second tab.The first fragment shows all the items in the list using resource cursor adapter. On clicking the second tab it opens an activity for creating new item and saves in the database. After finishing the activity, the first fragment with all list items are shown. But the newly created item is shown after a delay of 10 seconds. What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Use `setActivityForResult` to start your activity, when finishing update your listview/adapter.
I suggest not to open another activity create a fragment for second tab and after adding new row update your first tab